How I can recover my account
Several days when I become trying to get an acces to my accont.
How I can recover my account: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53124/safwane

What happened? You forgot your password? Email? Giving you an error?

@Starship: I cannot get access without any other reasons

What do you mean without another reason? What happens when you attempt to log into your account?

@Starship: I have created anew account https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1429594/safwanne

and maybe this is the  raeson

Probably yes. Are you banned at Math SE somehow? Looks all fine for me.

@πάνταῥεῖ: no , never

Why did you create a new one, what was your intention?

@πάνταῥεῖ: I hava installed a new windows and then I loss the access

Well, now you seem to have it again, so what's the actual problem?

Do you have access to the (Gmail) address you registered with? In that case, like most websites, it's rather simple.

@πάνταῥεῖ: then no problem if I get the access

We can't help unless you give details. What you mean "no access"? What happens when you try to login? Do you get errors? Please post screenshots, check the dev console (F12 in Chrome) for errors, etc.

@πάνταῥεῖ no, where did you see it? According to this, "last seen 2 days ago" - i.e. the OP hasn't logged in there for two days.

@Safwanne I don't think that would have caused it (creating a new account). When you install new windows you would have been logged out though. Nobody can help you until you say what happens when you try to log in.

Looks like a glitch by Stack Exchange when merging accounts, something failed at some point, might even be totally different accounts, and yours is just a victim. (We had several of those recently.)
For start, submit a contact support ticket (via the contact us page) asking to merge those two accounts:

Original
Current

Assuming both have same email, it should be done without further issues.
If that won't help, you'll have to submit another contact form, this time asking them to manually unmerge your account from this one, looks like something caused them to merge and that's not yours.
All in all. please be patient. Those things can take long time, if it's the later case (manual un-merge) even weeks. In the meantime, try to create a new account with different email and when things are sorted, ask to merge it with your older account.

It's not clear to me what indication there is of a glitch in account merging.  I don't see any evidence that there was merging involved at all.

Upon further inspection, I see what you saw: the new profile is somehow attached to an 11-year-old network account.  However, in that case, your advice is not sound: if their Math.SE profile is attached to an account that's not theirs, they should request that they be unmerged first, so that: 1) their account and possibly name will not be attached to content they did not write, and 2) the original account owner does not gain access to their profile.

@RyanM there were few "incidents" not long ago that manual merge of accounts caused the side effect of totally unrelated accounts being merged.  The symptoms are very much like what I see with that "hong kong" account which appears to be random. Anyway, only staff can really help and solve it, so the bottom line is submitting contact form, they can see what really happened.

They very likely need to specifically mention, when submitting the form, that their network profile is showing an account/profile that isn't theirs, though; staff need to know what problem they're trying to solve, which is not just merging accounts.
